# how to capture wifi router mac address without connecting to the netwotk

Tags: wireshark, aircrack-ng

i got d-link wifi repeater, at setup it displays all SSIDs in the area with their mac address without connecting.. 
so i was looking for command or utility for any OS that can capture mac address like that one did.

Answer (score 3):

### Physical/Software Access

If you own this networking device and you want to find its MAC address, it is better to use one of the following methods:

- Find the MAC address by physically looking at the device. Many networking devices will have the MAC address imprinted on a sticker.
- Use the built-in software to find it.

### Client device cli commands to scan BSSIDs

#### Linux

```
$ sudo iwlist <YOUR WIRELESS INTERFACE> scan
```

#### macOS

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport -s
```

#### Windows

```
$ netsh wlan show networks bssid
```